# i can't get a single document in firestore in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I am currently doing a project with angular and firebase, the problem is that when I want to get a single document at the moment that the console.log of the component appears, I get undefined. This is the code:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {
  AngularFirestore,
  AngularFirestoreCollection,
  AngularFirestoreDocument,
} from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Product } from '../interfaces/Product';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class ConexionService {
  private itemsCollection: AngularFirestoreCollection<Product>;
  private items: Observable<Product[]>;
    private itemDoc: AngularFirestoreDocument<Item>;

  constructor(private afs: AngularFirestore) {
    this.itemsCollection = afs.collection<Product>('Products');
    this.items = this.itemsCollection.snapshotChanges().pipe(
      map((actions) =>
        actions.map((a) => {
          const data = a.payload.doc.data() as Product;
          const id = a.payload.doc.id;
          return { id, ...data };
        })
      )
    );
  }

  listItem() {
    return this.items;
  }

  getOne(id: string): any {
    this.afs
      .collection<Product>('Products')
      .doc(id)
      .ref.get()
      .then((doc) => {
        if (doc.exists) {
          console.log(doc.data());
          return doc.data();
        } else {
          return 'Doc does not exits';
        }
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.error(err);
      });
  }
}
```

And this in the component

```
constructor(private _service: ConexionService){
     console.log('from component-', this._service.getOne('data_1'));
}
```

This is the console output:

> from component-undefined

I think the problem is that the function is called before the firebase data is opted, but I don't know how to solve it.

Comment: `getOne` doesn't return anything to the caller. That's why it says undefined.

Comment: what would be the way to do it correctly?

Comment: What are you expecting it to return?  It's performing an asynchronous query, so if you want to return the query results, you'll have to do it with a promise.

Comment: I want to return the document with the ID that was passed in the component

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Mentioned by @DougStevenson on the comments, the problem with your code is the lack of synchronism since the `get()` you are performing is asynchronous and will return after the `console.log()` in the constructor is executed, in order to fix it you will have to use a promise like in the below (untested) example:

```
getOne(id: string): any {
    return this.afs
               .collection<Product>('Products')
               .doc(id)
               .ref
               .get()
               .then((doc) => {
                   if (doc.exists) {
                       console.log(doc.data());
                       return doc.data();
                   } else {
                       return 'Doc does not exits';
                   }
                })
                .catch((err) => {
                   console.error(err);
                });
}

constructor(private _service: ConexionService){
    this._service.getOne('data_1').then(value => {
        console.log('from component-', value);
    });
}
```

So, what is happening here?! the `get().then()` inside the `getOne()` method represents what will happen once the promise is fulfilled, so if you use a `then()` after it's call in your contructor, it will wait for the promise contained in `getOne()` to fulfilled before executing your console.log, running synchronously.

Comment: the resolve function gives me a problem with catch. I tried removing it but it returns the document only in the service but not in the component, please can you help me that I'm new with promises in angular.

Comment: I thing I misplaced the `resolve()` try putting it inside the `then()` as it is on the edited answer

Comment: I just tried it and nothing comes back, could you tell me what that function works for

Comment: I have edited the answer once again, there is no need for a `resolve` or `reject`, the `then()` already represents the promise being fulfilled. I have added a more elaborate explanation in the answer. Hope this helps you.